# Fast reversible switching from hydrophobic(>120 degrees) to hydrophilic (<60 degrees)?

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension

I found few papers on reversible switching from hydrophobic to hydrophilic

1. [Reversible Hydrophobic to Hydrophilic Transition in Graphene via Water Splitting Induced by UV Irradiation](https://doi.org/10.1038/srep06450)
2. [Light-induced amphiphilic surfaces](https://doi.org/10.1038/41233)
3. [Reversible Switching between Superhydrophilicity and Superhydrophobicity†](https://doi.org/10.1002/marc.200400512)
4. [Reversible Transition of Graphene from Hydrophobic to Hydrophilic in the Presence of an Electric Field](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp3050466)
5. [Reversible wettability control of TiO2 surface by light irradiation](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0039-6028(02)01551-0)

but either the transition was too slow or the fabrication process is too cumbersome to apply.

I want a surface that can be reversibly switched between hydrophobic(>120 degrees) and hydrophilic(<60 degrees) with the use of external stimuli like temperature, light, roughness.

Comment: So which papers did you find - so we don’t waste time finding the ones you already have...

Comment: 1.Reversible Switching betweenSuperhydrophilicity and Superhydrophobicity**, 2. Light-induced amphiphilic surfaces, 3. Reversible Hydrophobic to Hydrophilic Transition in Graphene via Water Splitting Induced by UV Irradiation, 4. Reversible Transition of Graphene from Hydrophobic to Hydrophilic in the Presence of an Electric Field and several others.

Comment: Add it to your question, not as a comment and add the others you mentioned.